# Display Server Response Data onto HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Currently I have a working server that is able to receive and send data to my HTML webpage. However the problem is that I cannot encapsulate the data and display it as text on my webpage.

This is my HTML of the main body where I want the server response data in the id="response":

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TMwitub.jpg" alt="" width="740" height="220" />
  </div>
  <div class="boxed" style="height: 35px">
    <h1>HOME</h1>
    <div id="response" style="height: 93px; left: 270px; top: 283px; width: 564px;">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I will point out that EVERYTHING up to the success function works. My server is able to receive the POST and also send back the following JSON data:

Response Body:

```
{
  "details": "Log in success",
  "clientInfo":{ "firstName": "AAA", "lastName": "BBB", "balance" : "9999", }
}
```

Here is my JS (ready function is working --- everything is working, just not displaying response):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var messageType = "3";
            var cookie_name = "username"; 
            var cookie_name2 = "password";
            var YouWrote = getName(cookie_name);
            var YouWrote2 = getName2(cookie_name2);
            var userName = YouWrote;
            var password = YouWrote2;
            auth(messageType, userName, password);
        });



function auth(messageType, userName, password) {
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          //SEND TO SERVER URL
          url: "######",
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          data: '{"messageType": "' + messageType + '",
                  "userName": "' + userName + '",
                  "password" : "' + password + '"}',
          error: function (xhr, error) {
                   alert('Error!');
          },
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              $('#response').html(data.details + '\nHello ' + 
                                  data.clientInfo.firstName + ' ' +
                                  data.clientInfo.lastName + '. \nBalance:' +
                                  data.clientInfo.balance);
              }
         })
    }
```

Do I need to write some CSS for the id = response? I don't think so. I can't really think of why its not working and would appreciate some help/advice.

Comment: First of all, `async:false` doesn't work in jquery above 1.8 and whats that url `######`?

Comment: what error is showing in the browser console???

Comment: can i know what serverside language you are using(eg:python,php,c#..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data from the server must be string. something like:

```
 '{ "details": "Log in success", "clientInfo":{ "firstName": "AAA", "lastName": "BBB", "balance" : "9999"} }'
```

more over why you use format:

```
data: '{"messageType": "' + messageType + '",
 "userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : 
  "' + password + '"}',
```

instead why don't you use:

```
data: {"messageType": messageType,"userName":userName ,"password" :password},
```

Comment: Thats not the problem. I just debugged. THe problem is that userName and password is undefined.

Comment: hmm... every time you must check with the browser console first for ajax stuffs... :) @lancethestudent

Comment: I think im gonna close this up because the question i asked isnt even valid. Thx for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'll assume that your server side is in php.

Does your response header from the server is in JSON ?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also does your server side encode your data in json or you just echo your response ?

Like that

```
echo json_encode($your_data);
```

Remove async:false too.